# Why MP3 music files cannot be played on Note 3? ( It says, The music player does not support this type of audio file)

Tags: music, music-player, samsung-galaxy-note-3, mp3

Why MP3 music files cannot be played on Note 3 with the default audio player? (It says "The  music player does not support this type of audio file".)

This happens to some of my MP3 files when I try to play them on my Note 3. They were all fine when it was transferred to iPhone previously. They can also be played by my Windows  Player. I've tried deleting them from my Note 3 and transferring them back again which does not work.

Comment: Are you sure the iPhone didn't add a form of DRM? Can you find them in their original form?

Comment: It would be helpful to let us know which player you are using (they are many), or if you are using the stock player that came with your device.

Comment: I'm not sure how iphone work, but those files can be played as of their original form. @wbogacz

Comment: Sorry about the missing information. I'm using the player that comes with my device. @Colin

Comment: It seems [Galaxy Note 3 by default supports MP3](https://support.t-mobile.com/docs/DOC-9059), as also proven by your statement ("*This happens to **some** of my MP3 files*"). However, with current information, it's hard to guess the reason. I'd like to have 1 sample of the MP3 to test, but I'm afraid it could be counted as piracy.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and restarting my phone solved it.

Answer (score 0):

After trying multiple music players, I found that [Neutron Music Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.neutroncode.mp) will play all of the mp3 files that were otherwise unplayable!

Comment: Thank you for the referral to Neutron it did work for me.